# How to wait for multiple asynchronous calls from for loop?

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, es6-promise, ecmascript-2017

Code without any handling:

```
  for (i=0; i<dbImgCount; i++){
        (function(i) {
             imgDownload(FolderPath[i].FolderPath, function (next){
                var url = FolderPath[i].FolderPath;
                const img2 = cv.imread(imgDownload.Filename);
                match({url,
                    img1,
                    img2,
                    detector: new cv.ORBDetector(),
                    matchFunc: cv.matchBruteForceHamming,
                });

            })
        })(i);
      }
```

In the above code, `imgDownload` is an  [async function](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-downloader) which will download image, `match` will match features of downloaded image with another image. Need to execute a function after this `for-loop`.

How to restructure this code, using `Promise` or `async-await`, so that each call to asynchronous function is waited for and  **only after completing the `for-loop`**, flow continues?

---

Edited the code with `async-await`:

```
    FolderPath.forEach(FolderPath => {
        (async function () {
            var filename = await imgDownload(FolderPath.FolderPath);
            var url = FolderPath.FolderPath;
            const img2 = cv.imread(filename);
            imgs = await match({url,
                img1,
                img2,
                detector: new cv.ORBDetector(),
                matchFunc: cv.matchBruteForceHamming,
            });
        })();
    });

    function someFunction(){
       console.log("After forEach");
    }
```

How to execute `someFunction` **only** after `forEach`?

Comment: Does `imgDownload` support promises? If not, [start with that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572)

Comment: "*so that I can execute a callback function after this.*" - well, no, if you want to go with promises you would not take a callback function to call after this, you would instead return a promise for the matches.

Comment: I used image-downloader npm package, it supports Promise. https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-downloader

Comment: OK. Did you have a look at [their example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-downloader#usage-with-asyncawait) and tried to apply it for your case?

Comment: Using async/await? what should I do with that?


`var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {`
  `resolve('Success!');`
`});`

`promise1.then(function(value) {`
  `console.log(value);`
  // expected output: "Success!"
`});`

Use promise like this?

Comment: No, you should not use `new Promise`. You should change your deprecated `imgDownload` call to one that returns a promise, so that you can use that promise object.

Comment: Do you want the downloads to run concurrently or sequentially?

Comment: what is the problem with using async/await here?

Comment: Hey, my requirement is: first `imgDownload` will run and download an image, then, `match` will match the downloaded image with another one. After  the for loop, I want to execute another function.
Help me to restructure this in asynchronous way of doing things!

Answer (score 3):

With your last update, although you have used `async-await` inside `for-loop`, but that did't stoped your synchronous flow.

I'm assuming your `imgDownload` and `match` functions are returning promise.

Then new Code will be:

```
(async function () {

    // Next loop won't be executing without completing last.
    for (i = 0; i < FolderPath.length; i++) {

        var filename = await imgDownload(FolderPath[i].FolderPath);
        var url = FolderPath[i].FolderPath;

        const img2 = cv.imread(filename);

        imgs = await match({url,
            img1,
            img2,
            detector: new cv.ORBDetector(),
            matchFunc: cv.matchBruteForceHamming,
        });
    }

    // Now will wait for for-loop to end
    function someFunction(){
       console.log("After forEach");
    }
// End of async-await
})();
```

Here's a small sample example:

```
(async function () { 
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        x = await main();
        console.log(x, i);
    }
    console.log("Finally");
})();

// asynchronous main function
function main() {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(()=> { resolve('Done'); }, 5000)
    });
}
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`  This will be the output.

Comment: `await` is inside `async` function

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the comments.

```
   (async function () { 
        for (i = 0; i < FolderPath.length; i++) {
            var filename = await imgDownload(FolderPath[i].FolderPath);
            var url = FolderPath[i].FolderPath;
            const img2 = cv.imread(filename);
            imgs = await match({url,
                img1,
                img2,
                detector: new cv.ORBDetector(),
                matchFunc: cv.matchBruteForceHamming,
            });
        }
        console.log("After forEach");
    })();
```

This is **working** -  `"After forEach"` displays only after for loop.

---

When using `forEach` as mentioned in the answer above.

```
(async function () {

   // Next loop won't be executing without completing last.
  FolderPath.forEach(FolderPath => {

    var filename = await imgDownload(FolderPath.FolderPath);
    var url = FolderPath.FolderPath;

    const img2 = cv.imread(filename);

    imgs = await match({url,
        img1,
        img2,
        detector: new cv.ORBDetector(),
        matchFunc: cv.matchBruteForceHamming,
    });
});

// Now will wait for for-loop to end
function someFunction(){
   console.log("After forEach");
}
// End of async-await
})();
```

Output is - `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`.

I think `await` keyword won't be in scope of `async` function, when it comes under `forEach`, that should be the reason.

Comment: Yes, didn't noticed, `forEach` takes a `callback` function, which takes it out of scope of `async`, thus `await` is used outside `async`.

Comment: You could had just edited my answer with `for-loop`, as it's the solution for your problem.